# Express + node - routing 101

Tags: node.js, express

I am brand new to node and express and I hope that the SO community can help with this very introductory question.

I am simply trying to add an 'about' page with an /about route. 
I added `app.use('/about', about);` in app.js, then created an 'about.js' in the directory 'routes', I added the following to my about.js file (below), and I created an about.jade file.

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about');
});
```

However, when I go to http://localhost:3001/about I get:

```
Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
```

my about.jade file is in the views directory along with layout.jade and index.jade.

My files below

/app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var about = require('./routes/about');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/about', about);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

routs/about.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mounted the about router on `/about` via `app.use('/about', about);`, you would need to change

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about');
});
```

to something like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about');
});
```

in routes/about.js.